# JSON parsing with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON response from a server using javascript/jquery. This is the string:

```
{
"status": {
    "http_code": 200
},
"contents": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nDate: Tue, 07 Feb 2012 08:14:38 GMT\r\nServer: localhost\r\n\r\n {\"response\": \"true\"} "
}
```

I need to get the `response` value.

Here is what I am trying in the success function of my POST query:

```
            success: function(data) {
            var objstring = JSON.stringify(data);
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
            alert(objstring);

            var result1 = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result.contents[0]));
            alert(result1.response);

            alert(data.contents[0].response);
```

But so far nothing I have tried returns the correct result' I keep getting `undefined`, however the contents of `objstring` are correct and contain the JSON string.

Comment: Have you tested this in multiple browsers and still receive the same 'undefined' string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the JSON response itself contains JSON content. Depending on how you call the `jQuery.post()` method, you'll either get a string or a JSON object. For the first case, use jQuery.parseJSON() to convert the string to a JSON object:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(theAboveMentionedJsonAsString);
```

Next, get everything inside the `contents` property after the first `\r\n\r\n`:

```
var contentBody = data.contents.split("\r\n\r\n", 2)[1];
```

Lastly, convert that string to JSON and get the desired value:

```
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(contentBody).response;
// "true"
```

Answer (score 4):

First, set `dataType` to `json`.  Then `data` will be an object containing the data specified:

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
    alert(data.status.http_code);
    alert(data.contents);
}
```

Read [the API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) for more explanation of what these properties achieve. It would also probably help you to use a Javascript console, so you can use `console.log`, a much more powerful tool than `alert`.

Comment: This doesn't help getting the response value, are the escape codes stopping me from reading it. This doesn't work: data.contents.response

Comment: @danielbeard I hadn't seen that. My goodness me that's a ridiculous API.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
var objstring=JSON.stringify(data);
var result=JSON.parse(objstring);

alert("http code:" + result.status.http_code);
alert("contents:" + result.contents);
```